# What kind of events inform about WPF Window.Icon changes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, window

I would like to get informed whenever someone changes a certain WPF Window's Icon property. Which events do I need to listen to and how do I do it?

Thanks and best regards
Pascal

Comment: "Whenever Someone Changes" do you mean the user? how is the user changing the icon?

Comment: No, someone using my user control. I want to provide a special icon instance which they can set to trigger additional formatting options.